# Why is my exception handling causing an infinite loop?

Tags: java, exception, infinite-loop

I'm writing a method that will return an integer value. In the method I am prompting the user for the integer via console through the scanner class.

Because I am using the scanner method "scan.nextInt()", I am also checking for "InputMismatchException" error. I have placed the exception handling in a loop so that if the exception is caught the user is notified and the loop is reiterated. This will require the user to keep entering values until only an integer value has been entered.

However, my issue is after the first time it checks for the error, when it loops back, something is happening and the user is not prompted to enter a new value and the exception is thrown again. This of course results in an infinite loop.

I've researched and found a few cases related to the issue and I've tried performing relevant fixes but nothing I do seems to work and I don't understand what exactly is happening. Is the try block being skipped? Is there something wrong with my notation for the try block?

```
public static int inputCheck() {
int check=0;
int money = 0;
while (check==0) {
  boolean error = false;
  System.out.println("Please enter the amount of money your player has.");
  while (true) {
    try {
      money = scan.nextInt();
    }catch (InputMismatchException wrongInput) {
      System.out.println("Error. Please enter an integer value." + wrongInput);
      error = true;
    }
    break;
  }
  if (error==false)
    check++;
  }
return money;
}
```

*EDIT* Code has been edited and the "error" boolean value has been adjusted

Comment: Why do you have two nested loops?

Comment: Consider using `if(!error)` instead of checking for equality.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: @Oliver the 2nd loop was just one of the steps I took to try and fix this issue.

Comment: @Chief fixed, thanks for the tip, but irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: You REALLY need to step through this code in your IDE debugger.  You will learn a lot about the code and about debugging in general.  In fact, you should have done that before posting here. Please visit the [help] and especially read [ask].

Comment: My IDE does not have a debugger.

Comment: Re, "My IDE does not have a debugger?"  Really?  What IDE is that?  Who has the chutzpa to call that an IDE?

Comment: DrJava. I tried looking up the debugger but its not longer in the client like all of the documentation and tutorials claim.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your catch when you set error equal to true. Once error is set to true, your loop is constructed in a way that has no way of exiting because error is never set to false therefore check is never incremented. I would re-structure this this loop system in general, there are much better approaches to handling this.

Comment: Okay I have fixed this, however, although this fixes a potential infinite loop issue, my try block still seems to be being skipped over as It won't prompt the user for another value.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public static int inputCheck() {
    int check = 0;
    int money = 0;

    while (check == 0) {
        boolean error = false;
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of money your player has.");
        try {
            money = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error. Please enter an integer value." + e);
            error = true;
        }
        if (error == false) {
            check++;
        }
    }
    return money;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`while(true)` is never false, so the loop never terminates if it doesn't hit the `break` statement

Comment: There is a break right after the loop, however I have removed this while loop for the sake of simplicity.